# sql monthly existing user for all the historical records

Tags: sql, datetime, count, sum

I have a users database for user sign up time:

```
id,  signup_time
100    2020-09-01
001    2018-01-01
....
```

How could I find monthly existing user  for all the history record? Use the last day in the month as the cut off day, existing users means if I observe in July last day, 2020-07-31, this user had already signed up before 2020-07-01. If I observe in June last day 2020-06-30, this user had already signed up before 2020-06-01.

New users means if I observe in July last day, 2020-07-31, the user only sign up in July not before July, not after July between 2020-07-01 to 2020-07-31.
I could find monthly new_user by

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) AS new_user_count, year_month
FROM(
SELECT id,
             date_part('month', signup_time) AS signup_time_month,
             date_part('year', signup_time) AS signup_time_year,
             concat(date_part('year', signup_time),'-',lpad(date_part('month', signup_time)::text,2,'0')) AS year_month, signup_time
             
      FROM users)
GROUP BY year_month
```

Similar as a for loop in other language:

```
observation_year_month_list = ['2020-04','2020-05','2020-06']

 for i in observation_year_month_list:
      
     if user signup_time  < i:
        monthly_existing_user_count+1
```

Comment: Please define "monthly existing user".  Desired results would help as would an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Seems like you'd just need a WHERE statement, where year_month < current year_month.  That's assuming "existing users" are ones that signed up earlier than the current month.

Comment: Just edited add explanation.

Comment: @NathanChampion But it's a rolling month, how could sql represent "current " year_month?  Current could be different month.

Comment: @newleaf So, you want the count of users who signed up in within the last month, and as today is 9th September, that's everyone who signed up since the morning of 10th August?  Then to do that for all historical months too?

Comment: Yes. Let me edit my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to take the first login of each user, and compute a cumulative monthly count. If so, you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select 
    first_sign_month
    sum(count(*)) over(order by first_sign_month) total_users 
from (
    select id, date_trunc('month', min(signup_time)) first_sign_month
    from mytable
    group by id
) t
group by first_sign_month
```

Since you seem to be using Postgres, I used `date_trunc()` to truncate the date to the first day of the month. You can use `to_char(signup_time, 'yyyy-mm')` if you prefer a string in the format you originally used.

Comment: Apparently, it's not calendar month, it's a rolling month based on 'today'.  As I understand it, with today being 9th September the most recent 'month' is 10th August to 9th September (inclusive, erg, sorry).  And, I presume, if today is 30th March the month becomes 1st March to 30th March (inclusive, erg, sorry again), as there is no 31st February...

Comment: @MatBailie: I understand you are referring to that comment from OP. I started answering before that popped up - so this is not how I understood the question.

Comment: This is a good way to find new users of each month. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand what you are trying to do.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS existing_user_count, year_month
FROM(
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(signup_time - DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())) AS day_diff, 
         date_part('month', signup_time) AS signup_time_month,
         date_part('year', signup_time) AS signup_time_year,
         concat(date_part('year', signup_time),'-',lpad(date_part('month', signup_time)::text,2,'0')) AS year_month, signup_time
         
FROM users
WHERE day_diff > 0)
GROUP BY year_month
```

--Hope this gets closer--

```
WITH View AS
(
SELECT year_month, COUNT(*) AS monthly_newuser
FROM(
    SELECT id, 
           concat(date_part('year', DATEADD(month, 1, signup_time)),'-'
                 ,lpad(date_part('month', DATEADD(month, 1, signup_time))::text,2,'0')) 
           AS year_month         
FROM users
GROUP BY year_month
)

SELECT year_month, 
       SUM(monthly_newuser) over (ORDER BY year_month) AS existing_user_cnt
FROM View
```

Comment: It seems you're using current time while I hope to get rolling count for each month but this give some idea.

Comment: Yes I did. I have modified the query. Check it out and let me know if that's what you're looking for...